# Lambda function exclude .csv.metadata files from the output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have a Lambda function that executing Athena query and exporting the output in csv file to S3 bucket.
Now in my S3 bucket I'm getting 2 files **.csv** and **.csv.metadata**

My questions is how can I exclude the .csv.metadata files?

```
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_1 =   "<MY-QUERY-HERE>"
                 
    database = "<MY-DB-HERE>"
    s3_output = "MY-S3-BUCKET"

    client = boto3.client('athena')

    response = client.start_query_execution(QueryString = query_1,
                                        QueryExecutionContext={
                                            'Database': database
                                        },
                                        ResultConfiguration={
                                            'OutputLocation': '<MY-S3-BUCKET>'
                                        }
                                        )
    return response
```

Comment: how are you planning to use the .csv file after you run the query? Depending on that I can provide couple of suggestions

Comment: Yes, i will use the .csv file and .csv.metadata i want to exclude.

Comment: If you are using Athena you can simply add a line to your lambda to rename these *.metadata files starting with underscore/dot (_/.) . this will hide metadata files from Athena.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what i need to add and where, and yes i am using Athena query in the Lambda function as you can see in the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added this to my S3 bucket policy, and it works like a charm.
Doing exactly what i need.
And you can chose any prefix/bucket you want.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StatementPrefixDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prefix/*.csv.metadata"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need that file, you can add 1 more line to delete that file in S3 bucket.

EDIT: you can try this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

s3.Object('your-bucket', 'your-key').delete()
```

Cause according to the document, we don't have any options to change the result items:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution

Comment: I Added this to my code and nothing changed, metadata files is still there.

Comment: Can you paste the code here? I just look in the documentation of boto3 and use this function: 

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object

Remember to replace bucket name and the key include path also, and the syntax of create client

response = client.delete_object(
    Bucket='examplebucket',
    Key='objectkey.jpg',
)

print(response)

Comment: so i need to replace my "repsone = client.start_query_execution" ?

Comment: You need to remove the file _after_ the query has finished In the code you posted you're only _starting_ the query, you don't wait for it to finish. The metadata file is written when Athena writes the results, at the end of the execution. Use `get_query_execution` in a loop until it's status is `SUCCEEDED` (or `FAILED` or `CANCELLED`) – but be aware that this will make your Lambda function run for as long as the query runs and cost more.